# COINS.PH login panel from vb.net winform

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I want to create a login form for coins.ph but the result isn't what I expected, once I clicked the Sign In button from the form, everything in the username and password textbox will be written in the webbrowser but it wont click the sign in button from the webbrowser. But when I tried clicking the sign in button from the webbrowser, it says that no data were written.

Heres my code:

```
 Private Sub BunifuThinButton21_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuThinButton21.Click

        For Each username As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If username.OuterHtml.Contains("name=""username""") Then
                username.SetAttribute("value", BunifuMetroTextbox1.Text)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        For Each password As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If password.OuterHtml.Contains("name=""password""") Then
                password.SetAttribute("value", BunifuMetroTextbox2.Text)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        For Each signIN As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            If signIN.GetAttribute("class") = "login-button login-form__button" Then
                signIN.InvokeMember("click")
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Or what other approach should I use which is easier for me, they said that web page changes elements sometime. If api, theres no api for login pages.

Comment: which webiste iss it? Include that so that we can test..

Comment: my bad, its in the title: Coins.ph/login is the site